# Atom equivalent of Emacs ctrl-u function

Tags: atom-editor

In Emacs, `ctrl-u 2 0 x` will repeat the x key 20 times.

Is there an equivalent for this in Atom? I'm using the `atomic-emacs` keybinding, but that seems not to include this.

Any advice?